# Crash "art::ElfFile::Open(unix_file::FdFile*, bool, bool, bool, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>"

Tags: android, crash

Google Play has reported a large number of the following crashes from a few devices. I want to emphasize it is a very small number of devices (fewer than 0.01% of devices running the app):

```
signal 7 (SIGBUS), code 2 (BUS_ADRERR)
art::ElfFile::Open(unix_file::FdFile*, bool, bool, bool, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>*, unsigned char*)

backtrace:
  #00  pc 0000000000140c58  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ElfFile::Open(unix_file::FdFile*, bool, bool, bool, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>*, unsigned char*)+160)
  #00  pc 000000000030c445  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ElfOatFile::ElfFileOpen(unix_file::FdFile*, unsigned char*, bool, bool, bool, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>*)+64)
  #00  pc 000000000030c6ab  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ElfOatFile::Load(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>> const&, unsigned char*, bool, bool, bool, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>*)+98)
  #00  pc 000000000030ca23  /system/lib/libart.so (art::OatFile::Open(int, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>> const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>> const&, unsigned char*, unsigned char*, bool, bool, char const*, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>*)+418)
  #00  pc 000000000031257b  /system/lib/libart.so (art::OatFileAssistant::OatFileInfo::GetFile()+454)
  #00  pc 0000000000310bdd  /system/lib/libart.so (art::OatFileAssistant::OatFileInfo::Status()+36)
  #00  pc 0000000000310b8f  /system/lib/libart.so (art::OatFileAssistant::IsUpToDate()+58)
  #00  pc 00000000003169e3  /system/lib/libart.so (art::OatFileManager::OpenDexFilesFromOat(char const*, _jobject*, _jobjectArray*, art::OatFile const**, std::__1::vector<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>>>*)+246)
  #00  pc 00000000002e3349  /system/lib/libart.so (art::DexFile_openDexFileNative(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, _jstring*, _jstring*, int, _jobject*, _jobjectArray*)+100)
  #00  pc 0000000000076793  /system/framework/arm/boot-core-libart.oat (offset 0x76000) (dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative+194)
  #00  pc 00000000000ea1eb  /system/framework/arm/boot-core-libart.oat (offset 0x76000) (dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile+186)
  #00  pc 00000000000eb851  /system/framework/arm/boot-core-libart.oat (offset 0x76000) (dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements+560)
  #00  pc 00000000000eb3b5  /system/framework/arm/boot-core-libart.oat (offset 0x76000) (dalvik.system.DexPathList.<init>+516)
  #00  pc 0000000000149eaf  /system/framework/arm/boot-core-libart.oat (offset 0x76000) (dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.<init>+110)
  #00  pc 0000000000a05dc9  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x3ac000) (com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader+568)
  #00  pc 0000000000a05e33  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x3ac000) (com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader+58)
  #00  pc 0000000000676a97  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x3ac000) (android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader+278)
  #00  pc 0000000000676d35  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x3ac000) (android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader+84)
  #00  pc 000000000067ed67  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x3ac000) (android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked+2110)
  #00  pc 000000000068123d  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x3ac000) (android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader+76)
  #00  pc 00000000006815e1  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x3ac000) (android.app.LoadedApk.getResources+320)
  #00  pc 0000000000771e0d  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x3ac000) (android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext+140)
  #00  pc 000000000075baf3  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x3ac000) (android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication+4434)
  #00  pc 00000000007582fd  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x3ac000) (android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage+5788)
  #00  pc 00000000009107d1  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x3ac000) (android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage+136)
  #00  pc 0000000000912ecb  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x3ac000) (android.os.Looper.loop+1162)
  #00  pc 000000000076157b  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x3ac000) (android.app.ActivityThread.main+674)
  #00  pc 0000000000418375  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub_internal+68)
  #00  pc 00000000003f1a5b  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+222)
  #00  pc 00000000000a1043  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+154)
  #00  pc 00000000003510dd  /system/lib/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::InvokeWithArgArray(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, art::ArtMethod*, art::(anonymous namespace)::ArgArray*, art::JValue*, char const*)+52)
  #00  pc 0000000000352525  /system/lib/libart.so (art::InvokeMethod(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jobject*, _jobject*, unsigned int)+960)
  #00  pc 0000000000303249  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Method_invoke(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jobject*, _jobjectArray*)+40)
  #00  pc 00000000001121ff  /system/framework/arm/boot.oat (offset 0x10c000) (java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethodInternal [DEDUPED]+110)
  #00  pc 0000000000a0cd93  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x3ac000) (com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run+114)
  #00  pc 0000000000a12d19  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x3ac000) (com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main+2896)
  #00  pc 0000000000418375  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub_internal+68)
  #00  pc 00000000003f1a5b  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+222)
  #00  pc 00000000000a1043  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+154)
  #00  pc 00000000003510dd  /system/lib/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::InvokeWithArgArray(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, art::ArtMethod*, art::(anonymous namespace)::ArgArray*, art::JValue*, char const*)+52)
  #00  pc 0000000000350ef9  /system/lib/libart.so (art::InvokeWithVarArgs(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, std::__va_list)+304)
  #00  pc 00000000002949cd  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JNI::CallStaticVoidMethodV(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, _jmethodID*, std::__va_list)+476)
  #00  pc 000000000006cd03  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (_JNIEnv::CallStaticVoidMethod(_jclass*, _jmethodID*, ...)+38)
  #00  pc 000000000006ef2b  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::start(char const*, android::Vector<android::String8> const&, bool)+462)
  #00  pc 000000000000198d  /system/bin/app_process32 (main+724)
  #00  pc 0000000000088f55  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_init+48)
  #00  pc 0000000000001677  /system/bin/app_process32 (_start_main+46)
  #00  pc 0000000000017fa7  /system/bin/linker (__dl__ZN6soinfoD1Ev+14)
  #00  pc 00000000007feb99  [stack:ff55c000]
```

The backtrace does not indicate any code of the app. Could anyone offer a clue about the cause of this crash?

The above crash is from Xiaomi MiBox SAndroid 9 (SDK 28).
The app targets API 31

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this issue? We see similar crashes on a small number of devices.

Comment: @TheBestBigAl No, unfortunately.